# JavaScript game loop not working

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm having an issue with a game that I'm trying to make. Here is my code (very basic):

```
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var gameCanvas = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Global variables
var game;
game.fps = 60;
game._intervalId = setInterval(game.run, 1000 / game.fps);

// Game loop
game.run = function() {
    game.draw();
};

// Functions
game.draw = function() {
    // Background image
    var bgImage = new Image();
    bgImage.src = "img/background.png";
    // Player image
    var playerImage = new Image();
    playerImage.src = "img/player.png";
    // Draw
    gameCanvas.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    gameCanvas.drawImage(playerImage, 10, 10);      
}

// Game over
document.getElementById('end').onclick = function stop(){
    clearInterval(game._intervalId);    
}

// Run
window.onload = game.run();
```

The game doesn't run properly. Have I done anything wrong, or is there something I have missed out? Here is a link to the page: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33213779/Game/demo_me.html

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't run properly"?

Comment: @m90 if you have a look at the link, the canvas doesn't seem to load, either that or the images don't load. I can't tell if it's an issue with the game loop or the loading canvas/images code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that I can spot from what you are writing.

First one would be that you have to init your game-variable as an object:

```
var game = {}; // = {} initializes a new Object
game.fps = 60;
....
```

The second issue would be that you are not preloading your image sources (instead you are loading them 60 times each seconds....) so that the canvas is not able to access them as they are still being loaded.

Instead you could use a mechanism like this:

```
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.src = "img/background.png";
bgImage.onload = checkPreload;

var playerImage = new Image();
playerImage.src = "img/player.png";
playerImage.onload = checkPreload;

var loadedPics = 0;
function checkPreload(){
loadedPics++;
if (loadedPics == 2){
buildGame(); //start game
}
}

function buildGame(){
//inside this function you should be safe to refer to bgImage and playerImage
}
```

Note that this is **extremely** oversimplified as image preloading is an area stricken with a lot of pitfalls. But I guess you'll get the idea.

By the way **[this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/)** is a really good tutorial on game logic and all things canvas.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome the game generate a error that stop execution.  After **var game**;  game is undefined, then wen you do  **game.fps = something**,  is like you are doing **undefined.fps = something**, and javascript get angry.  The first patch would be to do **var game = {}**

And I don't understand why you are creating bgImage and player again and again in a loop. Even if that works, it could create problems.

```
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var gameCanvas = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 500;

      canvas.setAttribute("style","border:1px solid red");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    // Global variables
    var game = {};
    game.fps = 60;


    // Game loop
    game.run = function() {
        game.draw();
    };

    // Resource loader
    game.loader = function() {
        // Background image
        game.bgImage = new Image();
        game.bgImage.src = "img/background.png";

        // Player image
        game.playerImage = new Image();

        game.playerImage.src = "img/player.png";
    };                 

    // Functions
    game.draw = function() {
        // Draw
        gameCanvas.drawImage(game.bgImage, 0, 0);
        gameCanvas.drawImage(game.playerImage, 10, 10);     
    }
            game.loader();
    game._intervalId = setInterval(game.run, 1000 / game.fps);
```

This version of your code seems to work as you intended.

Comment: Wait, do you suggest I create a function for game? Please be a little more clear, thanks.

Comment: @Harry, the answer is very clear. `{}` is a new empty object.

Comment: Yes, I suggest to create a initlization function to load resources.

Comment: You'd still have to wait for the loading of the images. Canvas will sometimes stop working in case you try to use an image that is not yet loaded. Create some kind of callback in loader and wait to initialize the interval until all images are loaded.

Comment: Another thing you did wrong was tryiing to register a function in setinterval before it existed. I have moved the setInterval call to the bottom, and remove the unneceded game.run()

Comment: I don't know anything about Canvas, but Is dubious that you have to paint the background again and again, but maybe you need to?, sounds bad.  And IF m90 is right, you have to have a callback with onload to wait for these images to exist to draw.